# Availability of DBDB-V data

Tags: data-request

[DBDB-V](http://gcmd.nasa.gov/records/GCMD_DBDBV.html) is a digital bathymetric database (variable resolution) format. I'm particularly looking for test data in this format (to test FalconView amongst other tools).

I've found the OAML data at https://esme.bu.edu/download/index.shtml (which I have tried to load, but haven't yet managed to get to display in FalconView yet), but I'd really like to find something of a little higher resolution. It doesn't matter where, and it doesn't really matter how good the data is, just as long as it matches the standard.